# Check clustering validation metric with many rows

Tags: r, machine-learning, probability, clustering, sampling

I have a huge dataset containing $n=800,000$ rows and $d=50$ columns. I am applying clustering using the PAM approach (after feature reduction), and I want to select the optimal number of groups.

However, some algorithms would be computationally too expansive. Consider the simple Elbow method: I want to select a subsample of $n_1$ rows from my original data set so that $$n_1<<n$$ and check for the Elbow on this subset. In this case, how can I properly select $n_1$? Is there any specific suggestion from literature about sub sample size?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. You are titling it as "high-dimensional" but you mostly seem to be discussing cardinallity (sample size). Also, is 50 your dimensions before or after feature reduction?

Comment: @ttnphns You are right, i meant “high dimensionality “ as “high number of rows”, my fault. (50 is the number of features before reduction. With PCA I came to 4)

Comment: By "expansive" would you mean *expensive?*